# Laravel 9 multiple tag flush not working when flushing individual tags

Tags: php, laravel, caching, redis, laravel-9

I've noticed an issue with my Laravel application, and i'm not quite sure if i'm just doing something stupidly wrong, or there is a genuine issue.

So i'm storing and fetching my cached data with multiple tags on my `App\Models\User\User` model like below

```
public function getSetting(String|Bool $key = false) : Mixed {
    //Try
    try {
        return cache()->tags(["user_{$this->id}_cache", 'user_settings'])->remember("user_{$this->id}_settings", now()->addDays(1), function(){
            return $this->settings()->pluck('value', 'key')->toArray();
        });
    } catch(\Exception $e){
      //Logging errors here
    }
}
```

This function simply grabs all of the users settings and returns an array.

I am using 2 cache tags because I want to cover both scenarios

- The ability to be able to remove all cached items for a specific model (User)
- The ability to be able to remove a specific type of cache across all models (Users)

The Laravel [cache documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/cache#removing-items-from-the-cache) simply states to pass the tag (or tags as an array) that you want to remove.

So my thinking is that if I want to clear user settings cache for **all users**, I should be able to run the following

```
cache()->tags('user_settings')->flush();
```

and if I want to remove **all cache** for a specific user, I should be able to run

```
cache()->tags('user_1_cache')->flush();
```

But for some reason, only the second example (using `user_1_cache`) works? If I run the first example and try to clear all cache with the tags `user_settings`, the function returns `true` but does not clear the cache?

Am I doing something stupidly wrong or just completely misunderstanding how the cache tags work?

#### Versions

- PHP - 8.1
- Laravel - 9.3.8
- Cache driver - Redis

Comment: What is your cache retrieval logic?

Comment: I reproduced your scenario but it works as stated in the docs. `user_settings` flushes both entries.

Comment: @MostafaBahri The cache retrieval logic is simply a function that returns the initially stated function. I will update the question to reflect how I am retrieving the cached data

Answer (score 1):

I reproduced your scenario [here](https://laravelplayground.com/#/snippets/7dcf42ab-246d-40dc-9ba4-2aad2dbf5da3). It's working as stated in the docs.

```php
class User extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['id', 'name'];

    public function cacheSettings()
    {
        return cache()->tags([$this->getUserCacheKey(), 'user_settings'])->remember("{$this->id}_settings", now()->addDay(), function () {
            return $this->only('name');
        });
    }

    public function getSettings()
    {
        return cache()->tags([$this->getUserCacheKey(), 'user_settings'])->get("{$this->id}_settings");
    }

    public function getUserCacheKey()
    {
        return "user_{$this->id}_cache";
    }
}
```

These tests run with no problem:

```php
    public function test_cache_flush_all_users()
    {
        Cache::clear();
        $alice = new User(['id' => 1, 'name' => 'alice']);
        $john = new User(['id' => 2, 'name' => 'john']);

        $alice->cacheSettings();
        $john->cacheSettings();

        Cache::tags('user_settings')->flush();

        // both deleted
        $this->assertNull($alice->getSettings());
        $this->assertNull($john->getSettings());
    }

    public function test_cache_flush_specific_user()
    {
        Cache::clear();
        $alice = new User(['id' => 1, 'name' => 'alice']);
        $john = new User(['id' => 2, 'name' => 'john']);

        $alice->cacheSettings();
        $john->cacheSettings();

        Cache::tags($alice->getUserCacheKey())->flush();

        // only alice deleted
        $this->assertNull($alice->getSettings());

        $this->assertNotNull($john->getSettings());
    }
```

Not having all details of your implementation, perhaps you can figure out what is causing the issue.

Comment: Ok I will just have to investigate further to see if I can find what the specific problem is. Thanks for the write up and going through the effort of trying to help! Its much appreciated!

Comment: I have investigated this further I think I flagged a none issue (thats what late night coding can do to you!). I have realised what my actual issue was and I was getting confused. You cannot seem to clear cache using the `forget` function when a cache item is tagged. Please see your playground https://laravelplayground.com/#/snippets/7e925b77-fa92-4139-b32f-bfe4a29d9e82 , I have left some extra functions on the index.php with some comments on what is not working.